# How to make a jsgrid select field with autocomplete, showing the label but returning the value

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete, jsgrid

In jsgrid I'm trying to transform a regular type:select field into a autocomplete field, using https://codepen.io/beaver71/pen/rpaLEo as an example.
BUT how to transcribe this so that the form shows the labels but transfers the values to the database?
using:

```
var tags = [
  {label:"tag1", value:"201"}, 
  {label:"tag2", value:"202"}, 
  {label:"tag3", value:"203"}
];
```

instead of the default:

```
var tags = ["tag1", "tag2", "tag3"];
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. There is not really a way to do this. The Value attribute for a Field is going to represent the data entered into the field. You would either need a hidden input element, or store the data in another way for when the data is sent or posted.

Comment: Try using valueField: "Id", textField: "Name" to select the value / display text. Demos - Custom View